# get the string between starting character(s) and ending character(s)

Tags: javascript, regex, string

below I have given a simple string. It is just as example string, the pattern may remain the same but the string itself may change.

**Input : {#Hi#}, Please {#don't#} {#mark#} this {#question#} as {#duplicate#}.**

**The output should be: "Hi", "don't", "mark", "question", "duplicate"**

I have tried other approach in JS such as below. The below code has been added just for an example. Please refer to the input and output for your clarity.

```js
function extractString(template, initChar, finalChar) {
  let i = 0;
  let data = [];
  do {
    if (template[i] == initChar) {
      for (let j = i + 1; j < template.length; j++) {
        if (template[j] == finalChar) {
          data[data.length] = template.slice(i + 1, j);
          i = j + 1;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  } while (++i < template.length);
  return data;
}

extractString(
  "#adj#, #brown# fox jumps over the lazy #dog# new one.",
  "#",
  "#",
);
```

But the above works only for a single character.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe use [`{#(.*?)#}`](https://regex101.com/r/xjyrqp/1) as a starting point and try to extract the captured group.

Comment: Ok, let me try.

Comment: Or if you are sure there is no ‘#’ between the two #’s, better use #([^#]*)

Comment: There can be. I have just given an example, there can be any character between the starting and ending character(s).

Comment: if there is an aexample like this {#someth#}ing#} then you will have a problem.

Comment: will all words (in the input) be separated by a space ?

Comment: @TimeTrax, Yes.

Comment: split input by space. get array of all words in input. if word starts with initCharSequence check that word ends with finalCharSequence. if true, add to result.

Comment: @TimeTrax, But there are 2 starting charactars and 2 ending characters.

Comment: @TimeTrax, Could you post an example here?

Comment: thats why i used initCharSequence..
Something like this might help: (if you remove punctuations like comma and periods)


function checkWord(word, startsWith, endsWith){
    
    let startLength    = startsWith.length;
    let endsWithLength = endsWith.length;
    
    const startOfWord  = word.substring(0, endsWithLength);
    const endOfWord    = word.substring(word.length-endsWithLength);
    
    console.log(startOfWord);
    console.log(endOfWord);

    return startOfWord == startsWith && endOfWord == endsWith;
}

Comment: @TimeTrax Please post your code here. I am not able to understand in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the answer from Luke Garrigan, here is the sample code:

```js
let str = `{#Hi#}, Please {#don't#} {#mark#} this {#question#} as {#duplicate#}.`
let matches = str.match(/(?<={#)(.*?)(?=#})/g)
console.log(matches)
```

Comment: Thanks, @henry-li I will try this one.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Positive lookbehind and Positive lookahead to just extract whatever you've got between the `{` and the `#`.

`(?<={#)(.*?)(?=#})`

Which should group like the following:
[image]

Comment: Can you post a sample code demonstrating the above solution?